# What data structure shall I use to process a polygon mesh in a "subdivisional" way?

Tags: data-structures, graphics, mesh, octree

Here is the problem: I have a geometric mesh which contains a number of polygons(triangle) to be processed parallelly, thus I need to an efficient method to obtain the polygon data in specific area, ie, given the bounding box{(x_min,y_min,z_min),(x_max,y_max,z_max)}, I need to get a list of polygons that contains all the polygons locates inside (or partly inside) this cubic area. Is it possible?

The bounding box vertex shall locates on a set of uniform cartesian grid. I am not sure whether I made myself clear, the whole idea is somehow like a octree data structure, but I need to store a list of polygons in each node of octree.

Comment: There are numerous data structures you can use. The best one depends on your use case. Here are a few: Grid, Octree, kd tree, bounding volume hierarchy... What is your actual question?

Comment: @NicoSchertler   I want to compute a minimum distance field to the mesh surface using CUDA parallel architecture, ie, for every grid point in 3D spatial, find the nearest point to it on the mesh surface. CUDA architecture need the calculation contains as less logical calculation or branch as possible.